# Why do i have to call do_action('wp_footer')?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've started today with wordpress, I would like to know why do i have to call

```
<?php do_action('wp_footer'); ?>
```

before the `</body>` tag

Could someone also explain what is `do_action()`?

Comment: Also check out [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for further basic WP questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The do_action() creates a hook.  Basically it prints out the contents of the wp_footer function at the bottom of your page by calling wp_footer().  You can also override that and create your own functions to output the footer.

check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: no you don't need to include it, but it also outputs wp_print_footer_scripts() which some plugins use.

Answer (score 0):

These days you should be using

```
wp_footer();
```

Which does the same....

Source https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer#In_twentyten_theme